# Error: A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations

Tags: sql-server

When i run the following query, an error occurred saying:

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be
>   combined with data-retrieval operations.

How should I fix this?

Here is the query:

```
DECLARE @loanInstallmet float

SELECT TOP (1) 
    loan.loanID,members.offno AS OfficialNumber,
    loan.loanAmount,
    loan.interestRate,
    loan.NoOfInstallment,
    loanHistory.presentInstallmentNo,
    loanHistory.dateBalanceUpdate,
    (loanHistory.presentInstallmentNo + 1) AS InstallmentNo, 
    members.monthllyContribution AS MonthlyContribution, 
    @loanInstallmet = 
        CASE 
            WHEN  loan.remarks = 'Half' THEN ROUND(loanHistory.balanceAmount/ (loan.NoOfInstallment-loanHistory.presentInstallmentNo ), 0) 
            ELSE ROUND((loan.loanAmount / loan.NoOfInstallment), 0)
        END, 
    CASE 
        WHEN  loanHistory.presentInstallmentNo % 12 = 0 THEN ROUND(((loan.loanAmount-loanHistory.balanceAmount) * loan.interestRate / 1200), 0)
        ELSE ROUND((loan.loanAmount * loan.interestRate / 1200), 0)
    END AS MonthlyInterest, 
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,Getdate()),3)as recMonth,
    year(GETDATE())as recYear,
    loan.isRecovered as LoanIsRecovered,
    members.memberIsActive,
    loanHistory.status,
    ROUND((loanHistory.balanceAmount-@loanInstallmet), 0) AS BalanceAmount,
    loan.remarks
FROM loan
INNER JOIN members 
    ON loan.offNo = members.offno
INNER JOIN loanHistory 
    ON members.offno = loanHistory.offNo
    AND loan.loanID = loanHistory.loanID
WHERE 
    loan.isRecovered = 0
    AND members.memberIsActive = 1  
order by loanHistory.presentInstallmentNo DESC
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is saying what it means ! ;)

You can't do:

SELECT     TOP (1) loan.loanID,members.offno AS OfficialNumber, ....

at the same time as:

SELECT  @loanInstallmet = CASE WHEN  loan.remarks = 'Half' THEN

You are either retrieving data for your application, or you are setting the value of a variable. It's not logical to do both at the same time.

If you want to calculate @loanInstallmet and use it in future calculations you can do something like the following:

```
With tblLoanInstallCalc as (
SELECT     TOP (1) loan.loanID,members.offno AS OfficialNumber,loan.loanAmount,loan.interestRate,loan.NoOfInstallment,loanHistory.presentInstallmentNo,loanHistory.dateBalanceUpdate,(loanHistory.presentInstallmentNo + 1) AS InstallmentNo, members.monthllyContribution AS MonthlyContribution, 
    CASE WHEN  loan.remarks = 'Half' THEN ROUND(loanHistory.balanceAmount/ (loan.NoOfInstallment-loanHistory.presentInstallmentNo ), 0)  ELSE ROUND((loan.loanAmount / loan.NoOfInstallment), 0) END AS loanInstallmet, 
    CASE WHEN  loanHistory.presentInstallmentNo%12 = 0 THEN ROUND(((loan.loanAmount-loanHistory.balanceAmount) * loan.interestRate / 1200), 0) ELSE ROUND((loan.loanAmount * loan.interestRate / 1200), 0) END AS MonthlyInterest, 
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,Getdate()),3)as recMonth,year(GETDATE())as recYear ,loan.isRecovered as LoanIsRecovered, members.memberIsActive, loanHistory.status, loan.remarks
    FROM         loan INNER JOIN
                          members ON loan.offNo = members.offno INNER JOIN
                          loanHistory ON members.offno = loanHistory.offNo AND loan.loanID = loanHistory.loanID
    WHERE     (loan.isRecovered = 0) AND (members.memberIsActive = 1)  
)
Select *, ROUND((balanceAmount-loanInstallmet), 0) AS BalanceAmount
From tblLoanInstallCalc
```

tblLoanInstallCalc is a common table expression (CTE) and is pre-calculating the prerequisites before you try to add up the balance

Comment: how can I insert this output to another table?

Comment: You change the select statement (select ROUND((balanceAmount-loanInstallmet), 0)) into an insert statement whilst still inserting from tblLoanInstallCalc

Comment: If I want to do both, assign value to a variable and return data to user, Can I do it with one select statement, or I have to repeat the same select statement twice ?

Comment: I suppose the question I have to ask before I answer is, what do you intend to do with the value in the variable before you return data to the user ?